# Reading file in C++ until string

Tags: c++

I need to read HTML files and ignore the input until reaching the following tag     `<a class="member-modal"` then print the characters between that and the closing     `<div>` tag.

Below is the extracted line of the file of interest.

```
<a class="member-modal" href="https://website.net/users/membercard/890520">Phil Jankins</a>
                                </div>
```

Below is my approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string temp;
string delimet = "member - modal";

ifstream file;
file.open("in.txt");

getline(file, temp);
cout << temp;
while (!file.eof())
{
    if (temp.find(delimet))
        cout << temp;
    getline(file, temp);
}
file.close();

}
```

Comment: I would find a good html parsing library and use that.

Answer (score 6):

#### Unnecessary `#includes`:

You don't need `<cstdlib>` and `<iomanip>` for this program. Those can be removed.

#### Avoid `using namespace`:

`using namespace` in a source file for such a tiny program is fine, but don't make it a habit. Prefer to qualify the names with the namespace prefix (`std::`) when practical. Read a longer discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

#### Open the stream on declaration and let the destructor close it:

Instead of explicitly calling `open()` in your file, use the parameterized constructor to make your code more concise and direct:

```
std::ifstream file("in.txt");
```

Also, no need to explicitly close at the end of `main()`. The destructor will close the file automatically when the scope of declaration is exited.

Be sure to always check that the file was opened successfully! If it fails, you should at least print a message to let the user know about the problem.

#### Use the return value of `getline()` instead of `eof()`:

The canonical line reading loop in C++ is:

```
while (std::getline(file, line)) 
{
}
```

That can simplify you program quite significantly. You can still test specific error states with the methods `bad()`, `fail()` and `eof()`. See the documentation for [`std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/).

#### Incorrect use of `string::find()`:

You have misinterpreted the return value of [`std::string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/). This method returns *the position of the first character of the first match. If no matches were found, the function returns `std::string::npos`.*

Which means that testing it as in `if (temp.find(delimet))` will probably not work as you intended, since the return value is not a boolean.

The correct usage is:

```
if (str.find(substring) != std::string::npos) { /* found the substring */ }
```

Also note that `"member - modal"` is not the same as `"member-modal"`. `find()` will look for an exact match, including spaces, so your implementation will only find something in the input file if you replace the search string to match the contents of the file down to each space. A more flexible implementation could be achieved using C++ [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

#### Be more thoughtful about variable naming:

Names line `temp` and `delimet` convey little meaning.

`temp` should at the very least be named `line`, as that is what the variable holds (a line from the file).

`delimet` sounds like a misspelled "delimiter", so `delimiter` would be better. Other options include `needle`, for searching a [needle in a haystack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_in_a_haystack), `target`, for the target of the search, `wanted_string`, and the list goes on...

#### Properly indent `main()`:

Code inside `main()` is not properly indented to convey nesting into the function. Proper indentation is very important for code readability, so that must be fixed.

#### Summing up:

This is my suggest implementation, based on the original code and applying the above changes:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Alway check after opening to make sure the
    // file existed and was opened successfully.
    //
    std::ifstream file("in.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    // Since this is a read-only variable,
    // also mark is as `const` to make intentions
    // clear to the readers.
    //
    const std::string needle = "member-modal";

    // Main reading loop:
    //
    std::string haystack;
    while (std::getline(file, haystack))
    {
        if (haystack.find(needle) != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << haystack << "\n";
            // Prints 
            //  <a class="member-modal" href="https://website.net/users/membercard/890520">Phil Jankins</a>
            // once
        }
    }
}
```